# How do I add variable pricing and totals to my booking form?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

First off, I am trying to get there to be a spot that lists the price of the room selected.

Secondly, I need the price to total up if they choose multiple rooms or other items (once I get the pricing fixed, there will be options for boat rentals, spa treatments, tickets, ect. that they can add to the total of the room).

Thirdly, I am trying to figure out a way to show the price for each room and have that price change based on the dates that they pick. For instance, if they pick a weekday in the summer, it will show one rate that is different if they chose a weekend, or if they pick multiple days, it will show and tabulate the different rates for the weekend and the weekdays. As well as automatically give one night free if they reserve 7 or more nights. And have this change based on the season.

I think I am way over my head here, and if I am, as I suspect, is there a different way to go about this?

Here is a form that I am using:

https://jsfiddle.net/kg5wa2Lv/

And the code

```
(function($){
function floatLabel(inputType){
    $(inputType).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // on focus add cladd active to label
        $this.focus(function(){
            $this.next().addClass("active");
        });
        //on blur check field and remove class if needed
        $this.blur(function(){
            if($this.val() === '' || $this.val() === 'blank'){
                $this.next().removeClass();
            }
        });
    });
}
// just add a class of "floatLabel to the input field!"
floatLabel(".floatLabel");
```

Comment: Where do the set of rules come from for applying prices to rooms?

Comment: I haven't put them in as I am a bit lost on how and where to do that. I was going to use something like: http://jsfiddle.net/Wm6zC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to follow your ideas. That can be a problem at my side - so please don't get angry. :)

To the answer - can you have list of objects with information about each offer? That way you can tell total price - if something was changed then you can track changes, update object, or remove it from list - then sum up to get total.

Treat list of offers as an object - add_offer, remove_offer, change_offer - that are methods. Also sum_up should be separate offer. On change you need to trigger proper method, get new values, and place them into right places.

Other option is to think about angular... Personally I don't like that kind of advises "Problem - just use bigger library..." But it can solve this issue. With two way bindings you just place variable, and update it...

Comment: Okay... that helps. I am working on a php script to see if I can't get what I want it to do.

Comment: You're gonna take prices for the server side?

Comment: No. I just need something front end for customers to see.